# chrome developer tools - undock sources tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to undock the sources tab using Chrome developer tools?
If I had 3 monitors, I would like:

- Webpage to be on monitor 1
- Elements tab to be displayed on monitor 2
- Sources tab to be shown on monitor 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open several devtools tabs for the same target tab and choose a different view in each one.

Preparations:

1. exit Chrome by using the "Exit" command in the browser menu
2. run Chrome with `--remote-debugging-port=9222` command line

   - you can use any number in 1024-65535 range, 9222 is the default, just make sure it's not used by another program (there are tools to view open ports);
   - edit the Chrome shortcut in your OS/launcher and always use it to start Chrome;

Usage:

1. in Chrome open `localhost:9222`
   (the port number is the one you've specified in the command line)
2. click the entry for your target tab
3. move the tab to another display

Repeat as many times as needed.

Comment: For anyone else searching this issue, here's how to achieve point 1:

Exit any running-instance of Chrome.

Right click on your "Chrome" shortcut.

Choose properties.

At the end of your "Target:" line add the command line flags. For example: chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222

Launch Chrome like normal with the shortcut.

Comment: When I get to point 2, I enter "localhost:9222" into the address bar, but I get a "site can't be reached" message in chrome

Comment: Fantastic !!  I had to  exit Chrome via the "exit" command and it works a treat... Thanks very much.